# Warning: File C:\Users\UserName\.android\repositories.cfg could not be loaded. ( didn't work this command "flutter doctor --android-licenses")

Tags: flutter, android-sdk-manager, android-licenses

I've been trying to solve this error since one day. 
First I got this error

```
Exception: Android sdkmanager tool not found (/ usr / lib / android-sdk / tools / bin / sdkmanager).
Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK,
visit https://flutter.io/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions.
```

[Here is a Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFxto.png)

I tried to solve this error but couldn't solve it and I deleted Android Studio completely (sdk, gradle, .android ... etc). I reinstalled and flutter I got this error when I wrote doctor. [New errors Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlD1a.png)

```
C:\Users\Fatihh>flutter doctor --android-licenses
Warning: File C:\Users\Fatihh\.android\repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
4 of 7 SDK package licenses not accepted. 100% Computing updates...
Review licenses that have not been accepted (y/N)?
C:\Users\Fatihh>
```

Finally I made the decision to write here. I need help.
Android studio version:4.1.1
OS :Win 10
Flutter SDK :1.22.5
Android SDK:30.3

Answer (score 0):

First, open `Android Studio` and install `Flutter` and `Dart` plugins on it. 
Then run the command `flutter doctor --android-licenses`
Finally, clean your project, make sure packages are installed and run it

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter run
```

Comment: I deleted the plugins and reinstalled. However, the command "flutter doctor --android-licenses" did not work again.
After the command "flutter doctor --android-licenses" I can't proceed.

Comment: "C:\Users\Fatihh>flutter doctor --android-licenses
Warning: File C:\Users\Fatihh\.android\repositories.cfg could not be loaded.[================                       ] 42% Fetch remote repository...
4 of 7 SDK package licenses not accepted. 100% Computing updates...
Review licenses that have not been accepted (y/N)?"          It types like this and then switches to the new command line before I can press y

Comment: Do you have an idea? I'm thinking of resetting the computer as a last resort

Comment: Manually create the file `repositories.cfg` under `C:\Users\Fatihh\.android`

Comment: Tried and .cfg error gone but still not accepting licenses                -----                                -4 of 7 SDK package licenses not accepted. 100% Computing updates...
Review licenses that have not been accepted (y/N)?

Comment: Run the command `flutter doctor --android-licenses` and on prompt confirm by `Y`

Comment: Doesn't let me press y switch to new line .I tried pressing y repeatedly while installing the license, but it still didn't

Comment: Do not copy paste. Write it yourself and press Enter

Comment: I wrote the command "flutter doctor --android-licenses" myself, but it did not work.

Comment: After giving this error it skips to 1 line and then this line comes before I let me press y. "C: \ Users \ Fatihh>"